# Retrieving a set of model objects that are indirectly related

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 4 models:

```
class TransitLine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Stop(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(TransitLine, related_name='stops')

class ExitType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    people_limit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Exits(models.Model):
    TOKEN_BOOTH     = 0
    GATE            = 1
    REVOLVING_DOOR  = 2

    EXIT_TYPES = (
        (TOKEN_BOOTH, 'Token booth'),
        (GATE, 'Gate'),
        (REVOLVING_DOOR, 'Revolving door'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    stop = models.ForeignKey(Stop, related_name='exits')
    type = models.ForeignKey(ExitType, related_name='exits')
```

I have one `TransitLine` object. I want to retrieve all the unique `ExitType` objects that are related to the `Stop` objects of the `TransitLine` (that was a mouth full).

Some semi-pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
tl = TransitLine.objects.get(id=1)
exit_types = []
for s in tl.stops:
    exit_types.append([e.type for e in s.exits])
unique_exit_types = list(set(exit_types))
```

Obviously, prefer to do this in one `QuerySet` call. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it me or is the model code not syntax highlighting like it normally would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
ExitType.objects.filter(exits__stop__line=line).distinct()
```